# getting error "The server block is not well formed" in netframework.aspx

Tags: asp.net

I opened up a large asp.net project in Visual Studio 2010; the project hadn't been touched for a couple of months, and the last time I had it opened, it built fine. But today it's getting errors during the build -- EDIT -- actually, Build and Rebuild both work; it's not until I try to Start Debugging that the errors occur.

```
  DESCRIPTION.............................FILE...............LINE
 "The server block is not well formed"    netframework.aspx  275150
```

and the following unreadable garbage:

> Literal expressions like '<%$ AëÜË    ¾ø2µ¬GP‰¦M†M²·tÕEôâ3)úè¦¢Š7*ÃGzü‰v;§h¿ñÒÿÕùhXY&˜ŠÐ÷Îç&þÊoaãÙ,–ûm…iû^|J[jÜÏ±­R[˜ó-ü×?¦S8I FÙ`œ`h¶©)CO-qz†ô—„*„mó+‚ìW¼„ý–åC6Emo«„>v¥>¨C,íc«2•dŸwì9+®Vù@üãwš^(œè Î¾ñF4×ME½Ú"ÝÚd$eO›N ‹˜Î8±°K×E<·NØKäµ)›‚Ù¥¬ ý—Ÿ##”e¸fšæPÐ{³ãQèëZ/G*½Ci„å…€bØÇ½á_$ÄøÛ±ÝÆÅÇÀáèÅš¼”kôX¨ÇHŽEŸñÎ˜LJÑ”NÀ$_ü€ô>$Y,I ¥u»dFÒ~WH*”D:ì1<:êª©[k¥õ²éÍ"ìâ®hàŽ)Ûp7”d—rTÚÇICýp†5Å«¡@ØJª‡è›Þ"RËŠÚ‰Åi‰ï/ªîë 7±¶cYJ¯¬—àÖ’öGUéÒ ;î’mõnÛ¿Xè‹Oñ&BÉ¸Ä}ŽåíXÑ­¬¯ë3Ê*’;ëÔÙÆv½‡ sk)¾ÀÈBk±mvõò3c]¾UsLq/¶Ùî~')ÛraÀÖ,ó››Kì¦é…¾QtÃ$šÁl¸"èGæ¨˜´aÔ}qÛžòn!=ÎéCáê©H¢J7C5ˆQ»™bXO“ø³ê¶®^'d0ï0”ÃæBD›“©/©;“îqe_Åk/k“‚ Îµ­hnŸëœÍ<07Ó@ñ""'ÐÒ—g UQ5ósžýªí”vÓZ"\yzÈ„+ø_V»;wlmùÎ ñI+è¬“ª‚­ ãpñ+ÜŸt”z­SŠÈPíÒÑðw9#DUpÞJ«vú  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MYAPP\netframework.aspx  177272

How do I begin to troubleshoot these errors in a large project?  As I said, last time it was opened it built fine--- EDIT: and ran fine.

Comment: Something *REALLY* funky is going on there...

Comment: Hopefully you are using SVN (or similar). If yes, do a diff between the working version and this version.

Comment: Looks like an text encoding issue, did you recently update or check-it out from source control?  First thing I would do is open the file up in the editor, make some insignificant (white-space) change and re-save it.

Comment: I've made the edits and rebuilt.  Not using SVN -- all I have are daily backups.  We recently got a new firewall which is filtering HTTP traffic. Would HTTP traffic hitting a webserver on localhost go through the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

For what it matters now, for this problem on my machine, I found I was @Import(ing) a namespace in the partial view that was being called but the reference was not being used. I removed the namespace @Import and the error went away.